# zf 1.9.6 zend_soap: Function ("doString") is not a valid method for this service

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044213/zend-soap-server-with-wsdl-autodiscovery-doesnt-work-as-expected)

I'm trying to work with Zend_Soap using zend framework 1.9.6 and php 5.3.1.

#### soap.php (wsdl generator)

```
<?php
   require_once('Zend/Soap/Server.php');
   require_once('Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover.php');
   require_once('Soaping.php');
   $_WSDL_URI="http://server/soap/soap.php?wsdl";

    if(isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
            hadleWSDL();
        } else {
            handleSOAP();
        }
  function hadleWSDL() {
        $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
        $autodiscover->setClass('Soaping');
        $autodiscover->handle();
    }

     function handleSOAP() {
     global $_WSDL_URI;
        $soap = new Zend_Soap_Server($_WSDL_URI); 
       $soap->setClass('Soaping');
        $soap->handle();
    }
```

#### Soaping.php (web service class)

```
<?php
class Soaping {

   /**
    *
    * @param string $str
    * @return string 
    */
    function doString($str) {
        return $str;
    }

}
```

#### client.php - client

```
<?php
   require_once('Zend/Soap/Client.php');
   $_WSDL_URI="http://server/soap/soap.php?wsdl";
       $client = new Zend_Soap_Client($_WSDL_URI);
       $client->doString('aaa');
```

when i execute the client.php file i get the error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] Function ("do_math") is not a valid method for this service in /usr/local/ZendFramework-1.9.6/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php:1090 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/ZendFramework-1.9.6/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php(1090): SoapClient->__soapCall('do_math', Array, NULL, NULL, Array) #1 [internal function]: Zend_Soap_Client->__call('do_math', Array) #2 /home/ufk/Projects/xpogames-development/xpo/soap/client.php(6): Zend_Soap_Client->do_math(1, 1) #3 {main} thrown in /usr/local/ZendFramework-1.9.6/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php on line 1090`

#### xml that is created by following the link http://server/soap/soap.php?wsdl

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://xpogames/soap/soap.php" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Soaping" targetNamespace="http://xpogames/soap/soap.php"><types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xpogames/soap/soap.php"/></types><portType name="SoapingPort"><operation name="doString"><documentation>do string</documentation><input message="tns:doStringIn"/><output message="tns:doStringOut"/></operation></portType><binding name="SoapingBinding" type="tns:SoapingPort"><soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><operation name="doString"><soap:operation soapAction="http://xpogames/soap/soap.php#doString"/><input><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://xpogames/soap/soap.php"/></input><output><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://xpogames/soap/soap.php"/></output></operation></binding><service name="SoapingService"><port name="SoapingPort" binding="tns:SoapingBinding"><soap:address location="http://xpogames/soap/soap.php"/></port></service><message name="doStringIn"><part name="str" type="xsd:string"/></message><message name="doStringOut"><part name="return" type="xsd:string"/></message></definitions>`

i see that the function exists in the xml, why can't i use it ?

#### update

if i add the following function to the class:
          /**
           * Add method
           *
           * @param Int $param1
           * @param Int $param2
           * @return Int
           */
         public function math_add($param1, $param2) {
             return $param1+$param2;
         }
this function get recognized. but even if i change it to add_math2(), the function doesn't get recognized again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok it seems that php cached the first time i created a wsdl file and didn't recreate it.

soap caching can be disabled by the php directive  soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0

Answer (score 0):

You should add comment for function only, then declare parameter input, output. Example:

```
/**
* Add method
*
* @param Int $param1
* @param Int $param2
* @return Int
*/
```